# Handling form clear and submit message on successful submission - React

Tags: reactjs, multipartform-data

I am trying to add a few lines onto my form submit method to deal with the form component re-rendering with the initial state values when it submits. I have it so that I am able to post correctly however when it submits there is no way to tell if it has submitted properly and the data in the form stays the same.

Is there an easier way than the way I am attempting below? I only want to redirect to a fresh component when it has saved successfully.

Would getting a success message include involve handling the "res.send(200)" message from the backend API in some way?

```
const DiveLogForm = (props) => {

....

        // state for the current field value
        const [dive, setDive] = useState({
            diveTypeID: ``,
            diveSchoolID: ``,
            currentID: ``,
            visibilityID: ``,
            diveDate: ``,
            diveMaxDepth: ``,
            userID: props.user.userID,
            diveVerifiedBySchool: false,
            diveNotes: ``,
            diveSpotID: ``,
            redirectToForm: false,
            error: '',
            id: ''
        });

        .....

        const jwt = auth.isAuthenticated()

        ...

        function handleSubmitDive(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("diveTypeID", dive.diveTypeID);
            formData.append("diveSchoolID", dive.diveSchoolID);
            formData.append("currentID", dive.currentID);
            formData.append("visibilityID", dive.visibilityID);
            formData.append("diveDate", dive.diveDate);
            formData.append("diveMaxDepth", dive.diveMaxDepth);
            formData.append("userID", dive.userID);
            formData.append("diveVerifiedBySchool", dive.diveVerifiedBySchool);
            formData.append("diveNotes", dive.diveNotes);
            formData.append("diveSpotID", dive.diveSpotID);
            formData.append("photos", photos);
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            };
            axios.post("http://localhost:5002/api/divelog/createdivelog", jwt.token, formData, config)
            .then((data) => {
            if (data && data.error) {
                setDive({...dive, error: data.error})
            } else {
                setDive({...dive, 'redirectToForm': true})
            }
        })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make sure you declare this outside the component . 
const initialValue = {
            diveTypeID: ``,
            diveSchoolID: ``,
            currentID: ``,
            visibilityID: ``,
            diveDate: ``,
            diveMaxDepth: ``,
            userID: props.user.userID,
            diveVerifiedBySchool: false,
            diveNotes: ``,
            diveSpotID: ``,
            redirectToForm: false,
            error: '',
            id: ''
        }

// Now in the state when initializing you can do this 
const [ dive, setDive ] = useState(initialValue);

// In your handle submit when the request is successfull inside your then 
setDive(initialValue);
```